Simplifying the integral $\int{\frac{\ln(x)(x+1)}{(x-1)x}} \, \mathrm{d}x $
I was doing a problem and the following integral came up
$$
\int{\frac{\ln(x)(x+1)}{(x-1)x}} \, \mathrm{d}x 
$$
My first attempt was doing the change of variable $y= \ln(x)$ (it seemed logical), but after some time spent it brought me nowhere. My next attempt was trying to simplify the function in the following way:
$$
{\frac{\ln(x)(x+1)}{(x-1)x}} = A\frac{\ln(x)}{x}+\frac{B}{x-1}
$$
Where $A$ is a constant and $B$ is a constant or a function. I could not find $A$ nor $B$. My question is if $A$ and $B$ exist and if I have any function can I do this type of decomposition every time? Is there a way to know if such coefficients exist for an arbitrary function?

You need a polylog for this

You could do partial fractions on the nonlogarithmic portion,
$$
\frac{x+1}{x(x-1)} = \frac{2}{x-1} - \frac 1 x
$$
Then you have to consider the integrals
$$
\int \frac{\ln x}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x
\qquad
2 \int \frac{\ln x}{x-1} \, \mathrm{d}x
$$
The former is trivial (let $u := \ln(x)$ there). The latter, after a transform, requires the dilogarithm $\operatorname{Li}_2$ which can be written as the integral
$$
\operatorname{Li}_2(x)
= - \int_0^x \frac{\ln(1-\xi)}{\xi} \, \mathrm{d}\xi
$$
which the second integral becomes after an obvious transformation ($x = 1-\xi$).
I can't imagine you'll be able to achieve any more elementary form than this (and WolframAlpha suggests as much), unless your original integral is between very special values.
